# nth child selector causing javascript to get wrong display property

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

Trying to build a website that kind of lets you read chapters from a book. However I'm trying to implement a show more button so that the screen won't get cluttered.

I'm doing this by making the display:none with the css nth child selector and then using javascript to get all the elements with a display none and making them visible again.

However I noticed that when I use the nth child selector to make some elements hidden, javascript now says they all have a display of block.

```
{% for chapter in chapters %}
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12" id="chapter-list">
                <div class="chapter-link-container">
                    <a href="{% url 'chapter-detail' chapter.manga.slug chapter.slug %}">Chapter {{chapter.number}}</a>
                </div>
         </div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
#chapter-list:nth-child(2){
    display: none;
}
```

```
let listItems = document.getElementsByClassName('chapter-link-container')
for(i=0; i< listItems.length; i++){
    const style = getComputedStyle(listItems[i])
    console.log(style.display)
}
```

when log this it prints out block 4 times

[image]

However we know that the second child has a display none I ran this code again but only changed nth child to div just to make sure.

```
#chapter-list div{
    display: none;
}
```

and sure enough every display was none

[image]

Comment: the `display:none` is applied to the **parent** of  the elements you are checking, `display` property is not inherited from the ancestor elements - on a side note - id's in *valid* HTML are unique

Comment: I agree with @Bravo. Additionally changing properties with JavaScript that have been originally set by css is prone to unwanted results. If your component will refresh or something else will cause change detection to take effect, the properties that you have set with javascript will be once again reset back to the original properties set by css a.k.a they will be set back to ```none```. What you want to do instead is either change the class via JavaScript or set those value with JavaScript from the start.

Comment: @Bravo yeah I know they are but I was just following a tutorial. Using JavaScript is the best option then?

Comment: @OvidijusParsiunas Alright I’ll keep that in my mind. I just was following along with someone online, and they pulled it off this way, thanks

Comment: `best option` for what? for console.log? yes ... it's the bet option

Comment: Just to make that clearer than has been stated before: **`id` must be unique at all times.**